# In Excel 2007, in VBA editor, why when I type Worksheets(1). , Excel does not list the members of the Worksheet object? (and how to fix this)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba, autocomplete

The picture that explains the question:

[image]

Notes:

- I have Tools: Options: Auto List Members option selected
- Ctrl+Space fails
- I know that I can use the Object Browser to see, what members I can use with the Worksheet object, but it would just be easier, if Excel showed me the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Worksheets` object [Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238455%28v=office.12%29.aspx) returns an object (or in VB speak a Variant data type). The code completion dropdown doesn't know which methods to show because the return is not strongly typed to a `Worksheet` object. Short of Excel either changing the code to use a strongly typed collection or heuristically figuring out the data type there is no way to change this behavior for the Item property.

You can however assign the returned object to a typed variable and the code completion will work. For example:

```
Worksheet Sheet1 = Worksheets(1)
Sheet1.
```

You will get the completion list when you type the period after Sheet1. This is because the returned object is now cast as a `Worksheet` type and Excel knows what methods are associated with that type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, just to clarify (and so that I understand this correctly), in Excel VBA, there is no way to map or cast the object returned by the Worksheets.Item()  property, so that the returned object is _explicitly_ the Worksheet object? (~no way to explicitly change the _type_ of the object that the Item property returns).

Comment: Well there is no UI to do it. In Visual Studio there are third party programs that tie into the code completion feature to enhance it (we use Resharper for example). VBA uses similar tech so it might be possible for an add-on to do this. However, I don't know of any that do.

Comment: @trismarck falling asleep last night I thought of a way to get the completion list. I've edited the answer to include it. Hope that helps.